# Is it possible create pdf with dropdown field using jsreport and chrome pdf recipe?

Tags: jsreport

I was trying to generate the pdf with dropdown field using Jsreport with chrome pdf recipe so that use can select one of the value from the list and can save but i could not find a way to do that. Is it possible using chrome pdf recipe or should i use any other recipe like apache fop pdf etc..?

Answer (score 0):

chrome doesn't support creating pdf with forms. 
At this moment it is just part of the jsreport backlog to add support for pdf forms during postprocessing

Apparently it is difficult with fop, though perhaps possible
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32055510/1660996